# How can I use lapply, sapply or apply to filter a data frame in R?

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply

I am trying to remove all field that does not contain 10 digit numbers and those that have 10 zeros, I want to achieve this with the lapply or sapply or apply function. my code below does not work:

```
lapply(df, function(x) filter(x %like% "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" | !x %in% "0000000000"))
```

Comment: It would be easier to replace those values within the data.frame with another value, e.g. `NA`.

Comment: `lapply(df, function(x) x[!grepl('^(([0-9]{10})|([^0]{10}))', x)])`

Answer (score 0):

10 zeroes are part of 10-digit numbers so you don't need to test for them separately.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c('123456789', '123456789', '123'), 
                 b = c('0000000000', '2345', '1234'))

result <- lapply(df, function(x) grep('\\d{10}', x, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))

#$a
#[1] "123456789" "123456789" "123"      

#$b
#[1] "2345" "1234"
```

You can also use `nchar` to count number of characters.

```
result <- lapply(df, function(x) x[nchar(x) != 10])
```